# Spring Batch - Meta tables - Oracle 12C - Entries in UTC timezone

Tags: spring, timezone, spring-batch, metadata, oracle12c

We are using Oracle 12C DB for Spring Batch Application.
System timezone is PST.
but i want the Job and step related entries in metatables in UTC timezone.
Any suggetions?

Comment: Is your issue similar to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/871 (which is for postgresql) ? Have you tried to modify the DDL script provided by Spring Batch for Oracle by using the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006081?

Answer (score 1):

following the best practice, preset time as `UTC` is considered as best practice and to avoid future bugs With Spring Boot JPA, use the below code in your application. properties file and obviously you can modify the timezone to your choice :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC
```

or you can attach it directly as :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin://localhost:3306/linkedin?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

But to solve the problem you have two options:

1- `JPA Native Query` to select and cast an array of objects, for instance :

you can make use of the oracle feature to convert PST to UTC

```
select cast(coltime as timestamp) at time zone 'UTC' from ...
```

JPA repository :

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select cast(DD.Ch_Status_Validfrom as timestamp) at time zone 'UTC', za.first_name, za.birth_date, ts.salary\n" +
            "from employees za, salaries ts  \n" +
            "where za.emp_no= :id" +
            " LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20"
            ,nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object[]> findWithSalary(@Param("id")Integer id);

}
```

CommandLineRunner

```
@Component
public class LoaderBootStrap implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        List<Object[]> withSalary = employeeRepository.findWithSalary(10001);
    }
}
```

2- Convert date and time between timezone with java for instance (UTC+8:00) Asia/Singapore - Singapore Time to (UTC-5:00) America/New_York - Eastern Standard Time:

```
 private final void demo(){
     ZoneId assiaZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore");
     ZoneId americaZone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

     ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

     System.out.println("Current Time As UTC : " + zonedDateTime);
     System.out.println("Current time As America time : " + dateConvertWithZoneId(zonedDateTime, americaZone));
     System.out.println("Current time As Asia time : " + dateConvertWithZoneId(zonedDateTime, assiaZone));
        
}
        
 private final LocalDateTime dateConvertWithZoneId(ZonedDateTime actualDate, ZoneId withZone){

    ZonedDateTime date = actualDate;

    return date.withZoneSameInstant(withZone).toLocalDateTime();

 }
```